# Express JS 4.x Multer Basic Upload

Tags: node.js, express, upload, multer

I'm trying to upload an image in Express JS using the Multer middleware, but running into several issues when trying to set up the *absolute* simplest use case.

The only error I'm receiving is: 'POST /upload 500', and my POST callback is never entered.. so I'm not even sure how to debug this case. My code is as follows:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './public/photos/'}); // valid dir

app.post('/upload', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res, next){
  // This callback is never reached. 500 error.
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.files);
});
```

upload.ejs:

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <p><input type='text', name='photo[name]', placeholder='Name'/></p>
    <p><input type='file', name='photo[image]'/></p>
    <p><input type='submit', value='Upload'/></p>
</form>
```

I can't pick out any difference between this and the current npm Multer setup documentation. More than just 'how-to' fix this, I'd really like to know why this isn't working, and what's happening under the hood that's causing it to fail.

All help welcome. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I forgot to include 
    var app = express() in my sample above, but it is in my code. I compiled and ran my /upload route, and everything works fine. The 500 error occurs only after adding multer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! For one, my input names were not matching:
upload.single('photo[image]').

That's what was causing the 500 error. I had a couple issues after this that were caused by using an outdated req.file packet and were easily solved by referencing the up-to-date multer documentation.